# smbclient -M fails to send messages

Tags: samba, client

I would like to send messages to a network PC (from one Ubuntu system to another).

I used this command to send a message to myself for testing:

```
smbclient -M myName -b
```

But I get this error:

```
message start: ERRSRV - ERRmsgoff (Not receiving messages.)
```

command on remote machine:

```
smbclient -M remoteName -b
```

error is:

```
Connection to remoteName failed. Error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

`myName` and `remoteName` are `hostname` values. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a `NET SEND` style message is sent to a system running Samba, it will run the command specified in the `message command` configuration.  According to the `smb.conf` man page, messages will be rejected by default, which might explain what you're seeing:

> If you don´t have a message command then the message won´t be
>   delivered and Samba will tell the sender there was an error.
>   Unfortunately WfWg totally ignores the error code and carries on
>   regardless, saying that the message was delivered.

One program that can take these messages from Samba and display them on the desktop is LinPopup:

http://linpopup2.sourceforge.net/

I haven't tried it personally, and it doesn't appear to be packaged for Ubuntu, so you would probably have to build it from source.